# Combinatorics (Yahtzee)

Tags: combinatorics

Well I am trying to solve some math problems and I am stuck, I really need some help. Here are the problems, please feel free to help me out.

How many of the outcomes on a single "Yahtzee Throw" have:

1. four of a kind? (Example: 44446)
2. three of a kind? (Example: 44456)
3. two pairs? (Example1: 22334, Example2: 62565)
4. a full house? (Example1: 33322, Example2: 11666)
5. a large straight(There are two possible outcomes I think, 12345 or 23456)
6. yatzy? (Example1: 11111, Example2: 66666)

I am looking for clear and comprehensive explanations, otherwise I probably won't understand, I would greatly appreciate if you guys could take your time to really explain this to me like you would explain something to a child because I am having a hard time understanding this.

Regards!

Comment: There are a lot of questions here. Why don't you just ask one and see if the answer to that one gives you some insight into the rest? What are your thoughts on the number of yahtzees?

Comment: Also some people here have no idea what Yahtzee is and little inclination to look it up. I am guessing that you roll 5 fair dice, each with faces 1-6. Is that correct? So are you saying you have no ideas about how to solve 1. You have just shown 1 possibility. Can you think of any others? If all else fails, try writing them all down and counting them. There are not that many.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post, [Yahtzee probability](http://blog.plover.com/math/yahtzee.html), explaining in some detail how to calculate this.

For a single throw of five dice:

```
AAAAA      6     0.0772 %   
AAAAB    150     1.929   
AAABB    300     3.858   
AAABC   1200    15.432   
AABBC   1800    23.148   
AABCD   3600    46.296  
ABCDE    720     9.259  %
```

The left column is the dice pattern, so for example `AABBC` is two pair and `AAABB` is full house.  The middle column is the number of ways of rolling that pattern out of the 7776 possible rolls.  The right column is the chance of rolling the pattern, as a percentage.

Note that pattern `ABCDE` includes the large straights, which you may want to remove and count separately, and similarly some small straights are `AABCD` and some are `ABCDE`.

[This tiny web application](http://perl.plover.com/misc/enumeration/tabulate-dice.cgi) performs similar calculations for any number of dice.

Answer (score 0):

"I am guessing that you roll 5 fair dice, each with faces 1-6. Is that correct?"

Yes, that is correct. My problem is that I can't seem to find a pattern.

I would do it like this: (Since order matter in yahtzee, meaning, picking 3 and 2 is not the same as 2 and 3)

1. P(6, 2) to get the different combinations of numbers. Then you can choose the dices for the first element in C(5, 4) ways and for the last one in C(1, 1) way. If you do this you get the correct answer wich is 150.
2. P(6, 3) to get the different combinations of numbers. Then you can choose the dices for the first element in C(5, 3) ways, for the second one in C(2, 1) ways and for the last one in C(1, 1) way. If you do this you get a wrong answer, the answer I am getting is 2400 which is not accurate.

I could go on but you can clearly see that I don't have an understanding of this and need some help.

I also read the link that the above poster posted but it didn't seem to help really :(. It did to some extent but not so I got a grasp around it. And you also brought the poker game up in the blog, I seem to understand that one fine because the order in poker doesn't matter. An example would be, that you have a "King Diamond" there would be no way that another "King Diamond" would show up in play. But in Yahtzee if one of the dices is showing a number 6 that doesn't mean that another one can't show the same number.

Comment: You seem to know a different type of Yahtzee than I do: In the version I know, the order doesn't matter (indeed, you throw all five dice at once, and they are indistinguishable, therefore there's no way to even establish an order).

Comment: Ofcourse the order matters in Yahtzee? How many outcomes are there in Yahtzee? 6^5=7776, which means that 61111 is not the same as 11116. Where in poker D6-D2-D3-D4-D5 = D2-D4-D6-D5-D3, D standing for Diamond. So regarding to the dices, the order matters or not? Because one dice getting number 6 is not the same as another dice getting number 6?

Comment: A large straight is "2-3-4-5-6". But it does *not* matter which of the dice is 2, which is 3, which is 4, and so on. It just matters that each of those numbers appears. The same is true for all others. In no single case does the score depend on the order.